# how to update header information in php

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

I have an web application in Codeigniter in which I have already created web services. Now I have to modify this. But In web service to fetch parameter previous developer use code something like this

```
$this->headers = $this->input->request_headers();
```

When I print this->headers using print_r(this->headers); code I got following result

```
[Host] => localhost
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
[Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
[Cookie] => tml_CookieLogin=YTo1OntzOjQ6InVzZXIiO3M6MTk6ImFkbWluQHN1cHBvcnRlci5jb20iO3M6NDoidGltZSI7aToxNDY0MTUyNzA3O3M6MzoicHdkIjtzOjE0OiJTdXBwb3J0ZXIjMTIzJCI7czo4OiJ0YWtlbWV0byI7TjtzOjEzOiJjaGtyZW1lbWJlcm1lIjtzOjE6IjEiO30%3D; PHPSESSID=63bf42elr3lpi20i2ddr9o6m23; RF=200565ec69bf3792a78e740dc1c75e44ae803b4f
[Connection] => keep-alive
[Cache-Control] => max-age=0
```

But In web service, developer use something like this

```
$this->headers['Cinicoauth']
```

And I got the error like "Undefined index: Cinicoauth". So what is the issue?
How can I got this parameter?

Comment: This means 'Cinicoauth' does not exist in the header as simple s that.

Comment: Yes I know But I don't know how to add this into header when I call webservice from android or IOS app.

Comment: how about `$this->output->set_header('Cinicoauth: my-value');`? checkout [this doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_header)

Comment: Thanks buddy. @ichadhr